# Handle index order with sql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, algorithm

So, I have

- List of 'task' objects
- Each task have int 'streak'
- I'm always getting first object (index 0)
- Then I'm passing boolean value (true/false) from gui
- if true task.streak++
- else task.streak = 1;
- then I would like to move this object to task.streak * multipler( int 10) position

When I wasnt trying to use sql I was just:

- removing actual task from list
- divide list into two other lists A(indexes from 0 to task.streak * multipler) and B (task.streak * multipler+ 1 to list.size)
- Then just concatenate A(list) + actual task + B(list) into one single list

(ofc if task.streak++ > list.size then dont increment it)

How I can handle this algorithm with SQL? I will have something like 2k-10k records. Or there is a better way to do it?

Using this approach I should delete all records and insert them to DB(I don't think this is the best approach because of how much it have to do)

*I can switch the type of DB if needed

Comment: What have you done to solve this issue? Show the code you wrote.

Comment: So, in your non-SQL version, a task also has a zero-based list index position that is not actually a field of the Task object, is that true? So that when you remove the task from the list (i.e. from index 0) and insert it somewhere else, the effect is that index of tasks in A are decremented by one, and the task itself has a new index equal to size of A. That index value, which actually controls the *order* of the tasks are not present in the SQL? Any way, you need to show more context for us to understand.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, exactly.

Comment: If the index value, which controls *order*, is not present in the SQL, how do you know the order? As I said, you need to **show more context**, e.g. show us the table, so we can understand what you are talking about.